# Finding a recursive function that codes a relevant tree for a $\Pi^1_1(a)$ subset of $^k(^\omega\omega)$.

Tags: set-theory

So I am studying the chapter "$\Pi^1_1$ Sets and $\Sigma^1_2$ Sets" from "The Higher Infinite" and I got stuck when trying to come up with a definition for the desired function below.

---

Some definitions:

> Def $1$. For each $x \in {^\omega\omega}$, let $E_x$ be the binary relation on $\omega$ as  below:
>   $$ (m, n) \in E_x  \longleftrightarrow x(\langle m, n \rangle) = 0,$$
>   where $\langle m, n \rangle$ is the code for the tuple $(m, n)$.
>   And now let,
>   $$\text{WF} = \{x \in {^\omega\omega} \mid E_x \text{ is well-founded}\}.$$
>   Def 2. Fix an enumeration of ${^{<\omega}\omega}$, and for each $i \in \omega$, let $S_i$ be a $\Delta^0_0$ decoding of the sequence of members of ${^{<\omega}\omega}$. 
>   Def 3. We say that $T$ is a tree on ${^k\omega} \times \omega$ iff $T \subseteq \bigcup_{m \in \omega} {^k(^m\omega)} \times {^m\omega}$ and for each $(t_0, \dots, t_k) \in T$ and $m \in \omega$ we have that $(t_0|m, \dots, t_k|m) \in T$.
>  And for $w = (x_0, \dots x_{l-1}) \in {^l(^\omega\omega)}$, $l \leq k$, $T_w$ is that tree on ${^{k-l}\omega} \times \omega$ defined by,
>   $$(t_0, \dots t_{k-l}) \in T_w \longleftrightarrow \exists m( (x_0|m, \dots, x_{l-1}|m, t_0, \dots t_{k-l}) \in T).$$
>   Also we say that a tree $T$ is well-founded iff it is well-founded with respect to $^*{\supset}$, Where $^*{\supset}$ is point-wise reverse inclusion.

---

A useful Theorem that we are going to quote:

> Th(*). Let $a \in {^\omega\omega}$ and $A \subseteq {^k({^\omega\omega})}$. Then $A$ is $\Pi^1_1(a)$ iff there is a tree $T$ on ${^k\omega} \times \omega$ such that for any $w \in {^k(^\omega\omega)}$, 
>   $$A(w) \longleftrightarrow T_w \text{ is well-founded ,}$$
>   and the relation $\{(i, w) \mid S_i \in T_w\}$ is recursive in $a$.

---

The part of the book, which I have a problem with:

> By (*), for any $\Pi^1_1(a)$ set $A \subseteq {^k(^\omega\omega)}$ there is a function $f:{^k(^\omega\omega)} \rightarrow {^\omega\omega}$ (whose graph is) recursive in $a$ such that $A = f^{-1}(\text{WF})$.

---

My thoughts:

By (*) we have a tree $T$ for $A$. And going with intuition I think I must construct $f$ in such a way that for each $w$, $f$ codes $T_w$ so that when $w$ is in $A$ we know that $T_w$ is well-founded and the real coding it should be in $\text{WF}$. I have tried writing such $f$ but I can't handle the complexity (by complexity here I mean the complexity of the graph of $f$, which should be recursive in $a$). Anything I have written down was at best $\Pi^0_2$.

Sorry for the long post.

Comment: $f(w)(i,j)=0$ iff $S_j \subseteq S_i$ and $(i,w) \in T_w$ and $(j,w) \in T_w$. Isn't that obviously recursive in $a$?

Comment: @Jonathan, Yes it is but when we say the graph of $f$, wouldn't that translate into, $F(w, x) \leftrightarrow \forall i \forall j( S_j \subseteq S_i \wedge (i, w) \in T_w \wedge (j, w) \in T_w \leftrightarrow x(\langle i, j \rangle) = 0)$?

Comment: I don't think that this is what is actually meant, though I agree that the phrasing is confusing. Else the statement would be wrong. When we say that $f \colon \omega^\omega \to \omega^\omega$ is recursive, we do not mean that whether $f(x) = y$ is decided by a Turing machine on oracles $x$ and $y$. What we mean is that whether $f(x)(n)=m$ is decided by a Turing machine on oracle y.

Comment: @Jonathan, To be honest I am not familiar with the literature on Turing machines and oracles. And the only definition I know is: we say $A \subseteq {^r\omega} \times {^k(^\omega\omega)}$ is recursive iff it is both $\Sigma^0_1$ and $\Pi^0_1$. And the fact that he mentions the graphs of function throught the chapter, I don't think it is probable that it's a mistake.

Comment: This is weird. A $\Sigma^0_1$ subset of $(\omega^\omega)^2$ can never be the graph of a (non-empty) function, since a $\Sigma^0_1$ property holding true of $(x,y)$ only depends on an initial segment of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @Jonathan, well that's not good. So is this a major problem with the text? Or is there any quick fix, so that I can continue reading on?

Comment: The usual phrasing of (*) is that $f$ is a recursive (in $a$) function and not that the graph is $\Sigma^0_1$. See for example 4A.3. in https://www.math.ucla.edu/~ynm/lectures/dst2009/dst2009.pdf , and 3D. for the definition of a recursive function.

Comment: To be honest I remember that when reading the same chapter some time ago, I was confused by the very same issue. I just assumed that it was a typo.